# XSL-FO: Set fixed static-content height?

Tags: xml, pdf, xsl-fo

Is there any way I can set a fixed height for static-content in xsl-fo.
I added  height="20mm" attribute but it doesn't work.

My xsl is something like this:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after"
                     height="20mm">
                    <fo:block margin-left="5mm" margin-right="5mm">
                        <fo:table border-top="1px solid black">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="95mm" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="95mm" />
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>
                                            Entité
                                            Exercice
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>
                                            Page
                                            <fo:page-number />
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:static-content>
```

Can some guide me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

The `height` property does not apply to `fo:static-content` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_static-content).  Use the `extent` property on your `fo:region-after` instead (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#extent and https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_region-after).